# How to fix "data-key not found" when using Stripe Checkout?

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

I am using the custom code of stripe checkout and respecting everything but I am getting this error :

```
StripeCheckout.configure: 'data-key' is a required option, but was not found
```

It's not the first time I use the code, I use it before and everything was fine.

Here is the fulle code :

```js
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
});

document.querySelector('.stripe-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'Title',
    description: 'description',
    currency: 'eur',
    amount: 9700
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});


// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
```

- I copied the correct key (the one you see is a placeholder)
- The element with the class **stripe-button** is present in the page
- I used the same code a lot of time before and it worked fine
- There is no special issue with the website
- https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js is included before the code
- I tried the test and the live key, error with both
- I also tried other key that worked on other sites.

Here is a screenshot of the error and the code of stripe too

[image]

Did someone face the same issue before? I am pretty sure it's a small hidden thing!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After few hours of tests and turning around all the documentation I found the issue and it's related to CSS!

I was using the class **stripe-button** on the html element created in order to trigger the stripe action. It seems that the same class is also used by Stripe and it was creating a confusing in the JS code.

So never use this class when trying to integrate Stripe on your site : **stripe-button**

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks fine. My suggestions for the issue:

1. Try 'data-key' instead of 'key'. Less than 1%...
2. Verify your key, for example via Stripe web interface, https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
3. Remove mixed content error (https requests mixed with http). "You must serve the page containing the payment form over HTTPS as well", https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#does-checkout-require-https.
4. Check "Supported browsers" section, https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#what-browsers-does-checkout-support.
5. Investigate the backend of the project.
6. Try to run it in another environment, another network...
7. Compare to the project where it works. Does the same functionality still work in any of your projects?
8. Ask for help Stripe support or "other developers", https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#questions

Comment: thank you but i already did everything:
1) i changed with data-key
2) i verified the key and i used other keys that work in other sites 
3) i removed, i also tried in an empty page of this site, nothing too
4) did this too
5) the back end is within Stripe am only managing the front end
6) i did this before on other site and it works fine, this is what make confusing
7) yes it still works
8) i will do it if i don't find any issue

Comment: I found the issue and it's related to CSS ! check my answer below

Comment: yes no one can imagine to pick up exactly the same class used by them ! will try to notify them